# svn status won't detect unversioned files, how to make it?

Tags: svn

I'm kind of at a loss here. From everything I've seen online, and from previous experience, `svn status` should return a list of modified files AND unversioned files. I rely on parsing out the "?" that indicates unversioned files so that I can delete them. However, `svn status` is only returning the list of modified files right now! I've tried it in verbose mode as well, and no luck. What is going wrong?!

EDIT: TortoiseSVN is also failing to find the unversioned files! I updated to the latest version in an attempt to fix this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the unversioned files aren't being ignored via an svn:ignore property?

Comment: @RobertGroves I was 99% they weren't ignored, but now that I double-check, it looks like someone did ignore them! Thanks Robert! If you make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe those files are ignored? Try:

```
svn status --no-ignore
```

Comment: Also I just want to say that TortoiseSVN should put some sort of UI element indicating ignored status. They just look unversioned :\

Comment: If it gave you an indicator it wouldn't be ignored then, would it? :) 

You get a '?' to indicate unversioned; it's a subtlety for sure, but there you have it.